CSS Not Loading for Browsable APIs in Django with DRF Despite Whitenoise
I am working on a Django project utilizing Django Rest Framework for APIs. I've encountered an issue where the CSS is not loading for the browsable APIs.
I am using Whitenoise to serve static files, but the problem persists.
Here’s the relevant part of my settings.py:
STATIC_LOCATION = "assets/"
MEDIA_LOCATION = "media/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "assets",
]

STATIC_ROOT: str = "static"
MEDIA_ROOT: str = "media"
STATIC_URL = "/assets/"

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    #...
]

STORAGES = {
    "staticfiles": {
        "BACKEND": "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage",
    },
}

My custom css and js are stored in assets dictory and i want to store correct static files in static dir.
I've followed the standard configuration for Whitenoise, but its rendering a blank page without html and css for the DRF browsable API. I have also tried without whitenoise, and it is serving html file without statics(css and js).
Any suggestions or guidance on what might be going wrong or what else I should check would be greatly appreciated!

did you run collectstatic, which folder does it create?  STATIC_ROOT seems not to be as in guide https://whitenoise.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django.html#make-sure-staticfiles-is-configured-correctly

@iklinac yes, i already ran collectstatic and it got created under static in project root.
